# Mapping Tori and Monodromy

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, fibration

I have a question regarding the right setup for mapping tori. Let me give the definitions that I use first.

Let $I$ denote the interval $[0,2\pi]$ and let $I^*$ denote the quotient of $I$ by the relation $0 \sim 2\pi$. Further, let $F$ be a smooth manifold, $f \colon F \rightarrow F$ a diffeomorphism, and define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $I \times F$ by $(0,x) \sim (2\pi,f(x))$. The Mapping Torus of $f$ is the manifold $E_f = (I \times F)/\sim$. It is not difficult to see that this is a locally trivial fibration over $I^*$.
A map trivializing over $I^* \setminus \{\pi\}$ is, for instance, given by
$$\psi([t,x]) = \begin{equation} \begin{cases} ([t],x), &\text{if } 0 \leq t < \pi \\ ([t],f^{-1}(x)), &\text{if } \pi < t \leq 2\pi. \end{cases} \end{equation}$$
A lot of references now claim that this fibration has monodromy $[f]$. First of all, to speak of monodromy we need to fix a loop. A natural choice would be $\gamma \colon S^1 \rightarrow I^*, ~\gamma(t) = [t]$. Let $q$ denote the obvious map $[0,2\pi] \rightarrow S^1$. Now the pullback bundle $E = (\gamma \circ q)^*E_f$ has a global trivialization given by
$$h \colon F \times [0,2\pi] \rightarrow E, ~h(x,t) = (t,[t,x]).$$
We have that $h(x,0) = (0,[0,x])$ and, hence, viewed as a map $F \rightarrow E_0 \simeq F$, $h(\cdot,0)$ is exactly the identity $id_F$. Therefore, the monodromy associated to $\gamma$ is $h(\cdot,2\pi)$. However, this map $$h(x,2\pi) = (2\pi,[2\pi,x]) = (2\pi,[0,f^{-1}])$$ is actually $f^{-1}$, not $f$.
Doing a similar calculation, we find that the monodromy associated to $\delta(t) = [2\pi-t]$ is actually $f$.

In conclusion, we would have assumed that the most natural setup (i.e. using $\gamma$) would lead to monodromy $f$. If my calculations are correct, then this does not hold, though. So, the question is: should we define the mapping torus via the relation $(0,x) \sim (2\pi,f^{-1}(x))$ instead, or do the textbooks simply not communicate that the "natural" monodromy of $E_f$ actually is $f^{-1}$? (Of course, the implicit question "Are my calculations corret?" also stands...)

Comment: One [normally uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_torus) the identification $(2\pi,x) \sim (0,f(x))$, rather than $(0,x) \sim (2\pi,f(x))$. Of course, these are equivalent up to replacing $f$ with $f^{-1}$ as you've pointed out.

Comment: Yes, that would solve it. My professor used the definition I wrote but maybe he just made a mistake himself. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your calculation of the monodromy? In particular, how is it defined and why is the lift unique? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167006/monodromy-when-fiber-is-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Sure, I can! :) And your observation in your linked question is correct. Since it wasn't the main point of my question, I cheated on that last bit of precision. What I should have said is that the monodromy is the isotopy class of $h(\cdot,2\pi)$, not the map itself. As to the definition I use: suppose you have a fibration $p \colon E \rightarrow B$ with fiber $F$.Take a closed curve $\gamma$ in $B$ and denote by $q \colon [0,2\pi] \rightarrow S^1$ the map identifying $0$ with $2\pi$. Then the pullback bundle $(\gamma \circ q)^*E$ is a bundle over $[0,2\pi]$ and, hence, admits a global...

Comment: ...trivialization (since $[0,2\pi]$ is contractible). Denote this trivialization by $\psi \colon F \times [0,2\pi] \rightarrow (\gamma \circ q)^*E$. Since $q(0) = q(2\pi)$, the fibers over $0$ and $2\pi$ are the same (not just diffeomorphic but literally the same). Choose $\psi$ such that its restriction to $F \times \{0\}$ is the identity. Then set $h$ to be the restriction of $\psi$ to $F \times \{2\pi\}$, which still is an automorphism of the same fiber. Now as an exercise: two different choices of global trivializations give rise to isotopic such $h$. This establishes well-definedness.

Comment: Addendum: for holonomy, you use a connection to define parallel transport maps. But there, too, once you pass to the isotopy class of the parallel transport map, the resulting object is actually independent of the connection (morally, because the space of connections is path-connected and that gives you an isotopy between the respective parallel transport maps). Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thank you very much